# How to select 2 ntn-childs and skip 1?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'd like to know if that possible to solve with ntn-child. I need something like  ◼◼◻◼◼◻◼◼◻

Comment: use as seclector: `:not(:nth-of-type(3n + 3))` It will select all items with exeption of every 3rd item (`3n`) starting at the 3rd item (`+3`): https://codepen.io/tacoshy/pen/qBXZprQ

Comment: @tacoshy really appreciate your help!